# How to interpret a 95% confidence interval of a proportion?

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret confidence interval of the difference in means in one sample T-test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/how-to-interpret-confidence-interval-of-the-difference-in-means-in-one-sample-t-t)

The prevalence of obesity in children to mothers who smoked throughout pregnancy was 6.2% with 95% CI 4.5%-8.3%. I wonder how to interpret this CI.